# .at not update value in a itertuples loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe that i need to groupby Name and then iterate over the group. If the value si 20 update that value to 25. The problem is that if I print the dataframe the value if update to 25 but in the same iteration the value row.Age is not update to 25.

How can I update the row to be set immediately before the assignment??

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D'],
        'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18, 21, 19, 18],
        'Size': [7, 7, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(by='Name').reset_index(drop=True)

df['New_age'] = 0

df_grouped = df.groupby(['Name'])

for group_name, df_group in df_grouped:
    for row in df_group.itertuples():
        print(row.Name, )
        if row.Age == 20:
            df_group.at[row.Index, 'Age'] = 25
           
        df_group.at[row.Index, 'New_age'] = row.Age
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Do you simply want: `df['Age'] = df['Age'].mask(df['Age'].eq(20), 25)`? Or `df['Age'] = df['Age'].map({20: 25}).fillna(df['Age'])`?